# Changing The Font Colour for a Select2 Option at the Change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 option element that detects and warns the user if he or she has changed the default setting by changing the background colour(using the code below)

```
$(document).on('change', ".ctaskSelector", function(e) {
 var val =  $(this).val();
 var index = $(".ctaskSelector").index(this);
 if ( val != taskData[index].task_ID)
    $(this).next().find('.select2-selection').css({'background-color':'red'})
 else
    $(this).next().find('.select2-selection').css({'background-color':'white'})
```

Changing the background colour is proving to be too intense as it masks out the text field.  Rather than changing the background colour I would like to just change the *font colour* of the *displayed item*.   I have tried just about all the css options ([How to change font color of select2 control using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748026/how-to-change-font-color-of-select2-control-using-css)
 but can't seem to find the one that will change just the selected option font color.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to change the font color for the selected option within that `select2`, try below codes:

**The reason is select2 will do below things:**

1. added some `<span>` into your `<select>`; (you can `console.log($('select').html())` to see what are added)
2. create one `<span class="selection">` under body then use position=absolute to place it above your `<select>`

so you need to get the id first (by `$('span[aria-owns]', this).attr('aria-owns')`),
then find out that element by `$('#'+ id)`, finally change the background or something else you like.

```js
$('select').select2();
//change the background-color for select
$('.select2 span').css('background-color', 'yellow')

$('.select2').click(function(){
  //you can uncomment below codes to see its structure
  //console.log($('.select2-container').html())
  //below change the background color for the input
  $('#'+$('span[aria-owns]', this).attr('aria-owns'))
    .parent()
    .siblings('.select2-search')
    .find('input')
    .css('background-color', 'green')
  //below change the font color for the selected option
  $('#'+$('span[aria-owns]', this).attr('aria-owns'))
    .find('li[aria-selected=true]')
    .css('color', 'red')
  //below change the font color for <select>
  $('>span>span>span', this).css('color', 'blue')
  //below change the background color for the arrow of <select>
  $('>span .select2-selection__arrow', this).css('background-color', 'red')
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="select2" style="width:100%">
  <option value="e1" >Element 1</option>
  <option value="e2" >Element 2</option>
  <option value="e3" >Element 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I think my question is confusing and will edit it.   I am able to change the background colour but what want to be able to do is change the font colour.

Comment: @Alexander, updated my answer. just change `background-color` to `color`.

Comment: Okay, thanks I can see how you change the colour of the options-> select items but I need to change the colour of the "selected item" that is displayed.  I will see if I can modify your code.

Comment: @Alexander updated, only change the font color for selected item

Comment: I really do have to apologise as I think I am not using the correct terminology.   When I say "selected item" I really should be saying "displayed item".   I will edit the question.  But I think your solution will work.

Comment: @Alexander, if you'd like to change the color for that `<select>`, just get the span which select2 added, then change its color.