# How to add text with different color inside <option> tag of Select?

Tags: html, html-select

I have tried doing this inline but didnt work:

```
<select id="pet-select">
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="cat"><h3 style="color:red">Cat</h3></option>
</select>
```

I couldnt find any solution anywhere, is it even possible to do that?

**EDIT:**

I didnt mention I am using Select2 and not the normal Select. It works in Select but not in Select2

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```css
select option:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}
select option:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id="pet-select">
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
```

If you use select2, then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748026/how-to-change-font-color-of-select2-control-using-css).

Comment: ah sorry I didnt mention I am using Select2 and not the normal Select. It works in Select but not in Select2