# Change font color in select2 multiple

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

Can I ask how to change the font color in select2 multiple? I want to change to black from the current white font.

[image]

Javascript code

```
$('#size').select2();
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Size</label>
    <select id="size" class="form-control" name="size[]" multiple="multiple">
          <option value="Small">Small</option>
          <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
          <option value="Large">Large</option>
    </select>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the `css` applied to the selected value?

Comment: Try adding the css `.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__display { color: #000 }`

Comment: Check out the link; it could be helpful. = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748026/how-to-change-font-color-of-select2-control-using-css

Comment: Do I need to add this line like this ```<select class="select2-selection--multiple select2-container--default select2-selection__choice__display>```?

Comment: You can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6eog3y7v/) .